# Directly convert splat to set

Tags: ruby

I'm using the below code to generate a `set` from a range:

```
my_set = *(1..10).to_set
 # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

As you can see, instead of getting a set, I get an array.

The statement works if I split it into two lines:

```
my_set = *(1..10)
my_set = my_set.to_set
 # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}>
```

How can I get it to work as expected **in one line**?

Comment: Note: use `require 'set'` to get sets to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already had a set. Splatting it (`*`) gave you the array. Just don't splat:

```
my_set = (1..10).to_set # => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Set.new` works as well with ranges:

```
Set.new(1..10)
 => #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}>
```

Just for fun, if you want to use splat operator (`*`):

```
my_set = (_ = *(1..10)).to_set
=> #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}>
```

Note, that you should use assignment if you want to splat range.